# Does ItemsTemplate+DataTemplate obscure bindings?

Tags: wpf, templates, binding

At several points in my current application, I have an ItemTemplate such as the following:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <ToggleButton  Margin="2,0" Content="{Binding}" Tag="{Binding}"  Click="ToggleButton_Click">
            <ToggleButton.IsChecked>

                <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource EqualityConverter}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag">
                    </Binding>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type cc:ToggleButtonPanel}}" Path="SelectedItem">
                    </Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </ToggleButton.IsChecked>
        </ToggleButton>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Now, I've stepped through the converter and it returns `true` and `false` as expected, but the controls do not change their `ischecked` state...  There are **no binding errors**, and this only happens when using an **ItemsTemplate/DataTemplate combo**.  Has anyone else seen this behaviour?

Comment: Hey there. Based on what you provided it's hard to tell where is the problem and what's the cause. Could you create a minimal compilable example to reproduce the issue you have? Just a side question: what are you trying to achieve? Provided xaml-code looks little awkward to me.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplist is have a list of objects given to a itemscontrol, and have each represented by a generic usercontrol. I inherited this code.  This same datatemplate code appears in several places, and I've been retrofitting it all with DependencyProperties that are lists, but there are some cases where the data template would be perfect if it would work.  Thanks